# Want to connect a already present queue to a topic binding using stomp in rabbitmq using stomp.js

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, rabbitmq, stomp

I have a queue present for a user, so that I could send direct messages using direct exchnage by using spring boot using below line

```
simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(userMessage.getTo(), "/queue/messages", user.getName() + " : " +userMessage.getMessage());
```

A user has subscribed to 2 things using these 2 lines in js

```
this.stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', this.showMessage, {});
this.stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/messages', this.showMessage, {});
```

but the above 2 subscriptions is creating 2 queues, but what I want is one queue which is created for /user/queue/messages and the same as binded by greetings to /topic/greetings.

Don't have an background idea how rabbitmq does it, so didn't try at current that much.